# Tapestry.FORM_VALIDATE_EVENT with Tapestry 5.3 and tapestry-jquery

Tags: jquery, tapestry

I am trying to do cross field validation on a simple change password form.  Eg, new and confirm passwords are the same, new password is different than old, etc.

It appears that I should provide a handler for the `Tapestry.FORM_VALIDATE_EVENT`, which I have, but I can't figure out the proper way to signal an error and provide a message.

The comments in the `tapestry-jquery.js` source indicate that I should sent `event.result` to false, but that didn't seem to do anything.  These comments also appear to be a copy/paste from the prototype version of the Tapestry library, so I'm not sure they actually apply.

I tried throwing an exception like other custom validators work, and that didn't seem to do anything.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
        $("#" + specs.form).on(Tapestry.FORM_VALIDATE_EVENT, function (event) {

            var $currPassword = $("#" + specs.currentPassword).val();
            var $newPassword = $("#" + specs.newPassword).val();
            var $confirmPassword = $("#" + specs.confirmPassword).val();

            if ($currPassword == $newPassword) {
                // throw "wtf";
            }

            if ($newPassword != $confirmPassword) {
                // throw "other wtf";
            }
            event.result = false;
            return event;
        });
```

Does anyone have a working example of cross form validation with `tapestry-jquery`?

Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, that shows how to report validation error in custom JavaScript validator in Tapestry 5.3.8 with "tapestry-jquery":

```
var field = $('#input-should-be-validated');
field.tapestryFieldEventManager(); //initialize
$.tapestry.utils.addValidator(field, function(value) {
   if(value is NOT VALID){
       var form = field.closest('form');
       form.formEventManager("setValidationError", true);
       field.tapestryFieldEventManager("showValidationMessage", "NOT VALID");
   }
});
```